# Need help with error when accessing admin panel

Tags: error, admin-panel

I recently installed a theme and then uninstalled it by removing the files. Now I can't access the admin panel without getting this error. I've tried manually deleting the cache, but that didn't fix it. It looks like Magento is trying to load a class that doesn't exist, but I can't find where in the code it is requesting this class. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I can't look up what version of Magento I'm on, but it is an old one. Maybe, 1.6 or older. Here's the error:

```
Warning: include(Mage/Megamenu/Model/System/Config/Source/Category/Attribute/Source/Block/Proportions.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/hannon/web/public/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Trace:
#0 /home/hannon/web/public/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage/Me...', '/home/hannon/we...', 93, Array)
#1 /home/hannon/web/public/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Megamenu_M...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Mage_Megamenu_M...')
#4 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1204): class_exists('Mage_Megamenu_M...')
#5 /home/hannon/web/public/app/Mage.php(432): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('megamenu/system...', Array)
#6 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(373): Mage::getModel('megamenu/system...')
#7 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#8 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#9 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#10 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(673): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#11 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(129): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(211): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(434): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(52): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#15 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(211): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#16 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(434): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#17 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#18 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit.php(55): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#19 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(211): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit->_prepareLayout()
#20 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(457): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#21 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(241): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('Mage_Adminhtml_...', 'category.edit')
#22 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(207): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#23 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(212): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#24 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#25 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#26 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(263): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#27 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(189): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#28 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#29 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#30 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /home/hannon/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /home/hannon/web/public/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /home/hannon/web/public/index.php(78): Mage::run('', 'store')
#34 {main}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it is the `Mega_Menu` module that is causing the issues here.

1) Use a find tool "Grep" or PHPStorm has a good means of finding a string within folders. Hunt for any reference to "Mega_Menu" that you might have missed when removing themes.

2) Remove all of the references that you find

3) If you still have issues after the above and clearing the cache it could be that there is a Database value that is invoking this. I had this once before and it was not a pleasant experience to resolve. I had to backup the database and go through custom tables etc looking for the extra code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used PhpMyAdmin to search for the phrase '%megamenu%' in all tables and got 3 hits on the eav_attribute table. Deleted 5 rows that were added recently and I'm back in business. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have removed any module with the name "Megamenu" in it from your `app/etc/modules` folder.

Comment: I did make sure to delete that file when removing the theme. Thanks for the suggestion.